# how I can set the result number for getProductSearchResults()?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

this code always return 10 records, anyone knows how to set 100?

Is for use the API of Google Cloud Vision Product Search.

```
 # get the name of the product set

 $productSetPath = $productSearchClient->productSetName($projectId, $location, $productSetId);

        # product search specific parameters
        $productSearchParams = (new ProductSearchParams())
            ->setProductSet($productSetPath)
            ->setProductCategories([$productCategory]);

        # search products similar to the image
        $response = $imageAnnotatorClient->productSearch($image, $productSearchParams);

        if ($productSearchResults = $response->getProductSearchResults()) {

            $results = $productSearchResults->getResults(); //this always return 10 results. 

            foreach ($results as $result) {

                # display the product information.
                $product = $result->getProduct();
                $productName = $product->getName();

            }
        }
```

Comment: After 30 seconds with google and the documentation I would suggest looking at `public ProductSearchParams setBoundingPoly(BoundingPoly boundingPoly)` to increase the boundary in which it looks for results

Answer (score 0):

There is no place to specify the number of product search results in [productSearchParams](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/reference/rest/v1/ImageContext#ProductSearchParams). BoundingPoly isn't related to the number of results. BoundingPoly is an optional parameter used to mark the area of the image that contains the product.